# How do I access a second repository on a server created using tortoise SVN

Tags: svn, repository, tortoisesvn

We have a machine on our lan and we check out of using tortoise subversion using 
svn://serverName/

e.g: svn://repoMachine/MainProject/trunk

I have created another repository on the repoMachine in a foder D:\TestDataRepository using tortoise command . My question is how to I browse to this repository from another machine? When I type svn://repoMachine in the URL of the Repository Browser all I can see is the contents of the original repository. What is the syntax for the URL? Do I need to configure something else on the server machine?

thanks
John

Answer (score 0):

You have just created a local repository. Now you have to setup a svn service. See [here](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.0/ch06s03.html).